# Kineticjs causes memory leaks. Does not release stage after it is destroyed

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, kineticjs, resource-cleanup

Our Single page Application generates a new stage for a new url route.
We have huge memory leaks. 
We have noticed that Kinetic.shapes and  Kinetic.names that are global variables are never cleared even after a call for stage.destroy().
The call bellow does not fix the problem:

```
        this.stage.destroy()
        Kinetic.shapes = [];
        Kinetic.names = [];
        Kinetic.stages = [];
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What version of kinetic.js are you using? It looks like they fixed a memory leak with `stage.destroy()` in version 5.1.0 
https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log